# How to create a web service in java with Reply To parameter

Tags: java, rest, callback, asynccallback, reply

Hi I am working with a **REST** web services in java and I am looking for a solution for handling the reply of the service. I want if client call the service it will pass another `URL` to the `REST` service so that it will automatically reply to that service not to client.

Comment: Don't know if i understood correctly, but inside the client code you could use httpclient from apache team, then you make another request to the service: Example: HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://targethost/homepage"); - Here is a quick tutorial: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

Comment: no that's not the case